# Only final row of array being displayed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot figure why only the final row of this multidimensional array is being displayed. Here is the array in `server.js`:

```
var ar = Array(4);

for(var i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
   ar[i]=Array(4);

 }

ar[0][0]='1';
ar[0][1]='2';
ar[0][2]="3";
ar[0][3]="4";
ar[1][0]='5';
ar[1][1]='6';
ar[1][2]="7";
ar[1][3]="8";
ar[2][0]="9";
ar[2][1]="10";
ar[2][2]="11";
ar[2][3]="12";
ar[3][0]="13";
ar[3][1]="14";
ar[3][2]="15";
ar[3][3]="16"
```

Then when I iterate over the array in `client.js` like this:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
          console.log(scores[i]);
          var someScores = scores[i];

      }
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = someScores;
```

it only displays `13,14,15,16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, define `somescores`, and with `.map` add values to `somescores`

```js
var ar = [
  ['1', '2', "3", "4"],
  ['5', '6', "7", "8"],
  ["9", "10", "11", "12"],
  ["13", "14", "15", "16"]
];


var someScores = '';

ar.map(function(i) {

  someScores += i + '<br>';

});
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = someScores;
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: I am attempting to display the 2d array as a grid instead of all on one line as you have it above.

Answer (score 2):

You are on every loop overwriting the variable

```
someScores = scores[i];
```

you need something like

```
someScores += scores[i] + ' ';
```

and an declaration and initializing previously (outside the loop) with

```
var someScores = '';
```

Working example:

```js
var scores = [['1', '2', "3", "4"], ['5', '6', "7", "8"], ["9", "10", "11", "12"], ["13", "14", "15", "16"]],
    i,
    someScores = '';

for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {   
    someScores += scores[i] + '<br>';
}

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = someScores;
document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = scores.join('<br>'); // faster
```

```html
<div id="display"></div><hr />
<div id="display2"></div>
```

Comment: So something like this? 
              var someScores = ' ';
              document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = someScores += scores[i] + " ";